# Pythonic way to "condense" a matrix

Tags: python, matrix

If I have the following matrix, which the input format is a list of lists:

| B | T | E |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 0 |

How can I construct the following python matrix:

```
       0     1
D = [[{1}, {1,2}],  0
     [{2}, {}]]     1
```

Where the elements of D, merge the pairs (B,E) with it's respective T.
Example: (0,1) in the above matrix, have T = 1 and T = 2, so in D matrix it should be a set {1,2}. Since there is no (1,1) pair, it should be a empty set {}.

How could a do that in a "pythonic" way?

Comment: What format is the input in? What have you tried?

Comment: The input format is a matrix in form of lists of lists. The solution I imagined was too long, with a lot of for iterations. I would like to know a concise way to achieve it

Comment: Is it a nested list, a numpy array, or a dataframe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
m = [[0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 2, 1], [1, 2, 0]]
d = defaultdict(dict)
for b, t, e in m:
   d[b][e] = [t] if e not in d[b] else [*d[b][e], t]

l = {i for b in d.values() for i in b}
result = [[set(k.get(j, [])) for j in l] for k in d.values()]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[{1}, {1, 2}], 
 [{2}, set()]]
```

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to guess what your input or output format is. If you are using pandas, you can do:

```
>>> data
[[0, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 1],
 [0, 2, 1],
 [1, 2, 0]]

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['B', 'T', 'E'])
>>> df
   B  T  E
0  0  1  0
1  0  1  1
2  0  2  1
3  1  2  0

>>> df.groupby(['B', 'E']).agg(set).unstack('E', fill_value=set())
     T        
E    0       1
B             
0  {1}  {1, 2}
1  {2}      {}

# OR,
>>> df.groupby(['B', 'E']).agg(set).unstack('E', fill_value=set()).to_numpy()

array([[{1}, {1, 2}],
       [{2}, set()]], dtype=object)
```